# Delete docs from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array that contains the documents id of the firebase. I need to click on the button to delete these documents in the firebase.

```
   deletePosts() {
  db.collection("users")
    .doc(user.email)
    .collection("posts")
    .doc(this.selectedPosts[0].id)  
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Success!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
},
```

How can I iterate documents and delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) as follows:

```
deletePosts() {

    let batch = db.batch();
    this.selectedPosts[0].forEach(element => {
        batch.delete(db.collection("users").doc(user.email).collection("posts").doc(element.id));
    });
    batch.commit()
    .then(() => {
       console.log("Success!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

---

Note that a batched write can contain up to 500 operations. In case you foresee that you could have to delete more than 500 you could use `Promise.all()`, as follows:

```
deletePosts() {

      const promises = [];
      this.selectedPosts[0].forEach(element => {
            promises.push(db.collection("users").doc(user.email).collection("posts").doc(element.id).delete());
      });
      Promise.all(promises);
      .then(() => {
         console.log("Success!");
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
      });

 }
```